# RANKING Function in DAX or MDX

Tags: reporting-services, mdx, ssrs-tablix, dax, ssas-tabular

How can i get result in attached image by DAX or MDX.Both can work for me.
( I will use DAX in Tabular Model and Will use MDX on SSRS part).

Sample Format
[image: Sample Format]

I tried below code but it didn't work.

```
WITH 
  SET OrderSet AS 
    Order
    (
      (
        [Dim Product].[Category Name].[Category Name].MEMBERS
       ,[Dim Product].[Subcategory Name].[Subcategory Name].MEMBERS
       ,[Dim Product].[Sub Subcategory Name].[Sub Subcategory Name].MEMBERS
       ,[Dim Product].[Product Name].[Product Name].MEMBERS
      )
     ,[Measures].[Order Quantity]
     ,BDESC
    ) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[RankOrderCount] AS 
    Rank
    (
      (
        [Dim Product].[Category Name].CurrentMember
       ,[Dim Product].[Subcategory Name].CurrentMember
       ,[Dim Product].[Sub Subcategory Name].CurrentMember
       ,[Dim Product].[Product Name].CurrentMember
      )
     ,OrderSet
    ) 
SELECT 
  {
    [Measures].[Order Quantity]
   ,[Measures].[RankOrderCount]
  } ON 0
 ,NON EMPTY 
    {OrderSet} ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works DW2016CTP3];
```

Comment: You can easily calculate rank in DAX. What is the structure of your table?

Comment: Can you please build dax code by above sample?

Comment: Does the sample data include a column with the `Order Count`? Or is it it a measure? If so how is it being calculated?

Comment: This sample is from standard  [Adventure Works]

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the problem. If I run this:

```
WITH 
  SET OrderSet AS 
    Order
    (
      (
        [Product].[Category].[Category].MEMBERS
       ,[Product].[Subcategory].[Subcategory].MEMBERS
      )
     ,[Measures].[Order Quantity]
     ,BDESC
    ) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[RankOrderCount] AS 
    Rank
    (
      (
        [Product].[Category].CurrentMember
       ,[Product].[Subcategory].CurrentMember
      )
     ,OrderSet
    ) 
SELECT 
  {
    [Measures].[Order Quantity]
   ,[Measures].[RankOrderCount]
  } ON 0
 ,NON EMPTY 
    {OrderSet} ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

I get this:

[image]

This looks like your desired output format - but I did not change the script - so what is the question?

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
DEFINE
VAR TableTMP1 =
    SELECTCOLUMNS (
        DimProductTable,
        "Product Name", DimProductTable[Product Name],
        "Sub Subcategory Name", RELATED ( SubSubcategoryTable[Sub Subcategory Name] ),
        "Subcategory Name", RELATED ( SubcategoryTable[Subcategory Name] ),
        "Category Name", RELATED ( CategoryTable[Category Name] )
    )
VAR TableTMP2 =
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        TableTMP1,
        "Order Count", CALCULATE ( SUM ( OrderTable[Quantity] ) )
    )
EVALUATE
    ADDCOLUMNS ( TableTMP2, "Rank", RANKX ( TableTMP2, [Order Count], ASC ) )
ORDER BY [Rank] ASC
```